# In Middleman that uses layout files, how can we append a js file for a specific html file during compile time?

Tags: haml, erb, middleman

I'm using Middleman, and I have a layout file that appends the jQuery CDN at the bottom for all `.html.haml` files. The layout file adds the jQuery CDN after all the html elements have been rendered.

One of my `.html.haml` files will have an additional js file that uses jQuery; however, it needs to see the jQuery CDN loaded first.

How can I tell Middleman that during compile time, append the js file for this specific `.html.haml` file?  I tried appending `= javascript_include_tag "jsfile"` at the bottom of my `.html.haml` file, but it errored out because it needed jQuery loaded first which won't happen until I reach the end of the layout file.

layout file:

```
!!! 5
%html{lang: 'en'}
  %head
  %body{class: current_page.data.body_class || 'page'}
    = yield
    // jQuery
    = javascript_include_tag  "//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"
    //I need to insert my js file here, but only for a specific HTML file.
```

P.S.  Also, I need to place the jQuery at the bottom of the file to make rendering more efficient, so I can't place it in the `head`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Providing my answer here after figuring out what worked for me:

First, I had to set a flag via `index_options` in the `.html.haml` file:

```
---
title: My Site
index_options: target_file
---
```

Then, I had to update the layout file with an `if` statement

```
!!! 5
%html{lang: 'en'}
  %head
  %body{class: current_page.data.body_class || 'page'}
    = yield
    // jQuery
    = javascript_include_tag  "//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"
    //Here's the added update:
    = javascript_include_tag "my_jsFile" if (current_page.data.index_options == "target_file")
```